# PHP find and replace, halving any numbers (e.g. col-xs-24 to col-xs-12)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, preg-replace

We're migrating bootstrap content from 24 columns to 12.

So I need to convert a string like:

```
<div class="col-xs-24 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
```

to:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
```

I can't get my head around the preg_replace required to extract the number, halve it, then put it back in place.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: @u_mulder, thanks, worked like a charm

Comment: Use [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to properly traverse your page, and _then_ use `preg_replace_callback()` to modify on the CSS class property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to u_mulder for suggesting preg_replace_callback.

Managed to do it with...

```
$string = '<div class="col-xs-24 col-md-12 col-lg-4">';

$out = preg_replace_callback(
            '/col\-\w{1,2}-(\d{1,2})/', 
            function ($matches) {
                return str_replace($matches[1], ($matches[1] / 2), $matches[0]);
            }, 
            $string
       );
```